# If statement in App Inventor

Tags: android, mobile, app-inventor

I'm designing a spaceship game in App Inventor. I have a label (lblScore) update when the ship is hit each time. When the ship is hit 3 times, I want the code inside that to execute yet it doesn't work. I've tried multiple variations of this, such as setting it to lblScore.Text instead. Any idea's on how I can address the issue?

[image: My Code]

Answer (score 1):

Is the lblscore a label?
If it is all you need to do is have a collision block saying whenever the spaceship gets hit, set lblscore = lblscore + 1
This should fix your issue but I would like to see all of your blocks

Answer (score 0):

Do you increment your `lblScore` in the `Ship.CollidedWith` event?

If yes, you should move your `if` statement there, but instead of using the `lblScore` component as currently, you should better use the `lblScore.Text` property instead.

Probably it would help us to help you, if you provide a screenshot of your `Ship.CollidedWith` event...